# 1064-Error on joomla 3 page

Tags: mysql, joomla

I'm building a website (locally), and after a little work - created new categories, deleted all the default ones, created some test articles, unpublished a couple of modules and edited other ones, I tried to open the page and I got this error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '`) AND c.extension = 'com_content' AND c.published = 1`' at line
>   10
>
> ```
> SQL=SELECT DISTINCT c.id AS CID FROM sbv9a_categories AS c 
>       LEFT JOIN sbv9a_content AS content ON c.id = content.catid 
>      WHERE ( content.id = ) AND c.extension = 'com_content' AND c.published = 1
> ```
>
> It appears the page you were looking for doesn't exist. Sorry about
>   that."

How can I fix this?

Comment: `WHERE ( content.id = )` <-- no brackets needed, and it requires an input. You cant tell a where statement to search for something without stating what it is. You can fill in a variable for this, as you did in the `c.extension` and `c.published`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given input value for `content.id` field. And hence the query is incomplete causing an `SQLException`.

```
WHERE ( content.id = ) AND c.extension = 'com_content' AND c.published = 1
 -------------------^ value is missing here
```

Comment: I have published one test article for every category, and after I disabled the News Module, the error was gone. Could it be because I don't have enough articles for the module that the error is showing?