# Joomla 1064 Error in Administration

Tags: joomla, components, mysql-error-1064

I am using Joomla 3.7.5. if I do some changes in configuration in some component in administration and want to save those changes it write me this:

> error 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY group_id DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1

I tried fix database (in Extension > Manage > Database), but it didn't help. I think there is some mistake in database with group_id table, but I am not sure where or how to fix it.

I tried it also on some old backup and it write something similar:

> error 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY group_id DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1 SQL=select group_id from #__user_usergroup_map where user_id = ORDER BY group_id DESC LIMIT 1

I haven't needed to change some settings in component configuration until now. So I am not sure for how long it is not able to save it without error 1064.

Any suggestions what to fix to repair this issue? I am not sure what is that mentioned Line 1 - is it line 1 in database or in some php file?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about joomla but looking carefully at this part of your error message

> select group_id from #__user_usergroup_map where user_id = ORDER BY group_id DESC LIMIT 1

leads me to suspect your problem is that the predicate in your where clause `user_id =` is incomplete.  A proper where clause would look something like `user_id = X` where X is a constant or some other expression.

Also, this sort of question may be more appropriate for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: I checked database, there is user_usergroup_map the table include 2 rows, where 1st is user_id and 2nd group_id, but all of them include that constant which is number. The table include users id and group id - it is giving permissions based on group to the user. Table looks without problems.

Comment: You probably need to figure out what is generating that particular query and why it's generating an incomplete expression `user_id =`.  As I said I don't know anything about joomla but my hunch is that a blank value is getting substituted into a template or experession for that query.

Comment: Also a quick glance at the **Related** links in the right column on this page shows [1064-Error on joomla 3 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562222/1064-error-on-joomla-3-page?rq=1) which looks very similar to the problem you're reporting.

Comment: Thank you, I just found the problem. It was problem with another component which were some problems inside php file. It called group_id trhoug this component, so it works if I disabled the component for a while.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  If you can it would be nice if you could add an answer explaining the root cause in more detail so others coming here with the same kind of issue would find a solution quicker.